# BER decode error

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I am doing the RSA signature verify, I will always get this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr'
  what():  BER decode error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't understand why I get this error, I never call the BERDecode before.

This my code segment, I had tried to trace the error it happens in the second line of the code:

```cxx
FileSource pubFile(publicKey_file.c_str(), true, new HexDecoder);
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier pub(pubFile);

FileSource signatureFile(sig_file.c_str(), true, new HexDecoder);   
if (signatureFile.MaxRetrievable() != pub.SignatureLength()) {
    return false;
}

SecByteBlock signature(pub.SignatureLength());
signatureFile.Get(signature, signature.size());

bool result = pub.VerifyMessage((const byte*)messages_file.c_str(),
messages_file.length(), signature, signature.size());

return result;
```

I could define what's going wrong, hope to get some help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Lilian. Note that you are trying to perform signatures giving *message recovery* (PSSR), is this on purpose? Generally SSA schemes are used.

Comment: Please provide your public key. Use a command like `hexdump -C <public_key>`. Add it to the question by clicking *Edit*. Also see [Keys and Formats](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a public key, which needs to be parsed before you can do any verification. For this you give the public key data to the `Verifier` constructor. This constructor tries to parse the public keys.

Now public keys are generally encoded data structures. These data structures are described by a data description language called ASN.1 or Abstract Syntax Notation 1 and encoded using a scheme called BER, the Basic Encoding Rules for ASN.1.

So what happens is that the constructor tries to read the public key and therefore calls `BERDecode` so make sense of the input. Unfortunately the input is likely not *binary* BER encoded at all.

So to resolve this you need to either use additional calls in your application to convert to BER or public key object, or you need to convert your key to BER. If the key is ASCII armored (PEM format) then you can use:

```
$ openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in <filename of key in PEM format> -outform DER -out <filename of key in DER format>
```

If this doesn't work please include the public key into your question so we can check why it doesn't parse.

Comment: I have tried that method but still doesn't work. This is my public key:    
**30819D300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818B0030818702818100DD2CED773D6F9AE4A63F2DAEEF9019C056D4A35F338764FAAE85EDCBFB13FC9E53F13CEFADEF58C65B501C3D2D13DCDE65282B7781C45259065F991C4184E6E6DEDB3087472B4AC4BDD74FDF4D3C893257D6872232651653A4882588C61C0F4FB096C5906F2F88E0480513A2B1BA6418869DB01C9D9A2FB4BECADE54658D552F020111**

Comment: That's an X.509v3 SubjectPublicKey. Could you have a look [here?](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) I've got some shopping to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to:

```
$ echo "30819D300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818B0030818702818100DD2CED773D6F9A
E4A63F2DAEEF9019C056D4A35F338764FAAE85EDCBFB13FC9E53F13CEFADEF58C65B501C3D2D13DC
DE65282B7781C45259065F991C4184E6E6DEDB3087472B4AC4BDD74FDF4D3C893257D68722326516
53A4882588C61C0F4FB096C5906F2F88E0480513A2B1BA6418869DB01C9D9A2FB4BECADE54658D55
2F020111" | xxd -r -p > key.ber
```

And then:

```
$ dumpasn1 key.ber
  0 157: SEQUENCE {
  3  13:   SEQUENCE {
  5   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 16   0:     NULL
       :     }
 18 139:   BIT STRING, encapsulates {
 22 135:     SEQUENCE {
 25 129:       INTEGER
       :         00 DD 2C ED 77 3D 6F 9A E4 A6 3F 2D AE EF 90 19
       :         C0 56 D4 A3 5F 33 87 64 FA AE 85 ED CB FB 13 FC
       :         9E 53 F1 3C EF AD EF 58 C6 5B 50 1C 3D 2D 13 DC
       :         DE 65 28 2B 77 81 C4 52 59 06 5F 99 1C 41 84 E6
       :         E6 DE DB 30 87 47 2B 4A C4 BD D7 4F DF 4D 3C 89
       :         32 57 D6 87 22 32 65 16 53 A4 88 25 88 C6 1C 0F
       :         4F B0 96 C5 90 6F 2F 88 E0 48 05 13 A2 B1 BA 64
       :         18 86 9D B0 1C 9D 9A 2F B4 BE CA DE 54 65 8D 55
       :         2F
157   1:       INTEGER 17
       :       }
       :     }
       :   }
```

You have a `subjectPublicKeyInfo`. I believe all you need to do is call `Load`, but it assumes you have a well-formed key:

```
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier pub;
pub.AccessKey().Load(pubFile);
```

Here's the whole program:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "pssr.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    std::string encodedKey = "30819D300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818B00"
        "30818702818100DD2CED773D6F9AE4A63F2DAEEF9019C056D4A35F338764FAAE8"
        "5EDCBFB13FC9E53F13CEFADEF58C65B501C3D2D13DCDE65282B7781C45259065F"
        "991C4184E6E6DEDB3087472B4AC4BDD74FDF4D3C893257D6872232651653A4882"
        "588C61C0F4FB096C5906F2F88E0480513A2B1BA6418869DB01C9D9A2FB4BECADE"
        "54658D552F020111";

    StringSource hexKey(encodedKey, true, new HexDecoder);

    RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier pub;
    pub.AccessKey().Load(hexKey);

    std::cout << "n: " << std::hex << pub.AccessKey().GetModulus() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e: " << std::dec << pub.AccessKey().GetPublicExponent() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And finally:

```
$ ./test.exe
n: dd2ced773d6f9ae4a63f2daeef9019c056d4a35f338764faae85edcbfb13fc9e53f13cefadef5
8c65b501c3d2d13dcde65282b7781c45259065f991c4184e6e6dedb3087472b4ac4bdd74fdf4d3c8
93257d6872232651653a4882588c61c0f4fb096c5906f2f88e0480513a2b1ba6418869db01c9d9a2
fb4becade54658d552fh
e: 17.
```

---

This may a bit too restrictive:

```
if (signatureFile.MaxRetrievable() != pub.SignatureLength()) {
    return false;
}
```

The actual signature length may be a tad bit shorter then `MaxSignatureLength()`, depending on how many leading 0's the exponentiation produces.

You might consider following one of the wiki examples. For example, from [RSA Signature Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Rsa_Signature_Schemes):

```
...

// Signing      
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Signer signer(privateKey);
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);

// Setup
byte message[] = "RSA-PSSR Test";
size_t messageLen = sizeof(message);      

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sign and Encode
SecByteBlock signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(messageLen));

size_t signatureLen = signer.SignMessageWithRecovery(rng, message, messageLen, NULL, 0, signature);

// Resize now we know the true size of the signature
signature.resize(signatureLen);

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Verify and Recover
SecByteBlock recovered(
    verifier.MaxRecoverableLengthFromSignatureLength(signatureLen)
);

DecodingResult result = verifier.RecoverMessage(recovered, NULL, 0, signature, signatureLen);

if (!result.isValidCoding) {
    throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Invalid Signature");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Use recovered message
//  MaxSignatureLength is likely larger than messageLength
recovered.resize(result.messageLength);
...
```

Comment: I think calling `Load()` may well resolve the issue. Note that about any RSA application uses a function called I2OSP, which converts the size of the signature-as-a-number to an octet string of the same size as the key size (or modulus size) in bytes. So I do not agree with that part of the answer. +1 none-the-less for probably solving the original issue of course.

Comment: Or do you have any indication that this final operation on the signature does not happen for recoverable signatures?

Comment: @Maarten - I believe `MaxSignatureLength` is `n-1`. I think OP is testing that the number of octets in the signature (`signatureFile.MaxRetrievable()`) is the same as the number of octets in the modulus (`pub.SignatureLength()`). I think that misses the mark a bit. I believe the condition or relationship that holds is `signatureFile.MaxRetrievable() <= pub.SignatureLength()`.

Comment: Check first paragraph [here](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_iso9796format.html)

Comment: Thanks @Maarteen. I was looking at the source code at [pssr.cpp](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/pssr.cpp) and I can't really tell what some of the expectations are. If the concern is incorrect your observations are available.